# RAID Configuration on Model Proliant DL380p Gen8

Tags: raid, hp, software-raid

how do I see the RAID configuration on HP Proliant DL380p Gen8 without the need to restart the server?

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the Smart Storage Administrator utility for Windows.

Here's the link to the current product:
https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_891c6d6803044e5db3e0c2a5ab